# ES6 object destructuring mandatory parameters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here is the function, `password` is mandatory but other `id` and `name` have default values:

```
function name({id = null, name = 'user', password}) { }
```

Results:

```
name();     //throws error as expected
name({});   //passes 'password' as 'undefined' - should've thrown error
```

How can I make this function throw an error if `password` is not provided using ES6 functionality?

Comment: Why don't you just validate incoming parameters in the function itself and throw if anything is invalid?  Heck an empty string or even a non-string could be passed for a password and that would pass any automatic ES6 stuff so you're going to have to validate the password field anyway.  Even if you had a hard typed language, you're still going to want to validate.

Comment: @jfriend00 I agree, but I just want to save code for scenarios where I only have to care about `undefined`. It is just `mcve`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Scimonster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41536154/157247) is spot-on about what the probelm is.

If you like, you can handle it a bit more declaratively by using a utility function to throw an `Error` in the function parameter list:

```js
// Utility function:
function throwRequired(name) {
  throw new Error(`'${name}' is required`);
}

function name({id = null, name = 'user', password = throwRequired("password")}) {
  console.log("All is good, password is: " + password);
}

try {
  name();     //throws error as expected
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Got error from name():", e.message);
}
try {
  name({});     //throws error as expected
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Got error from name({}):", e.message);
}
name({password: "foo"}); // works
```

That works because the initializer on a default parameter is only evaluated if it's required to fill in the default.

Comment: *(Doh! If you don't see `throwRequired` above, hit refresh.)*

Answer (score 4):

You could assign the same variable, it throws an error `Use before declaration`, if not given.

```js
function name({ id = null, name = 'user', password = password }) {
    console.log(password);
}
name({});
```

If set, then it works without error.

```js
function name({ id = null, name = 'user', password = password }) {
    console.log(password);
}
name({ password: 'foo' });
```

Comment: This article is also worth checking out: http://www.2ality.com/2014/04/required-parameters-es6.html

Comment: why is `,password = password}` different than `,password}` ?

Comment: because its a default assignment, with a variable which does not exist. and if it exist, then no assignment occurs.

Comment: default assignment is also `undefined`, how is that `undefined` is not equal to `an undefined variable`? I hope I am clear, this `undefined` hell is confusing me.

Comment: the variable `password` does not exists., even if RHS changed to `_`, it does not exists. it is not defined, and therefore it throws an error.

Comment: I know, but if I leave it as `,password` the default assignment is performed and that default assignment is also `undefined` *(I'm using vscode debugger to see this, in nodejs env)* and no there is no error in default. Error is only thrown when I `password = password` and this creates hell lot of confusion for me.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't make it required, you simply didn't provide a default value.

```
function name({id = null, name = 'user', password}) {
     if (password == undefined) {
        throw new Error('password is required');
    }
```

The reason it threw an error the first time is because it tried to destructure `undefined`, which is impossible.

Comment: I know it can be achieved using ES5 or traditional javascript code, but is there anyway I don't have to write this extra validation and use `ES6 functionality` just like `usecase 1`?

Comment: No, the "validation" is simply a side effect of destructuring.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** This is an ugly hack using the default parameters, and I prefer [@Scimonster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41536154/5157454).

You can actually run a function, and even an IIFE as a default param. The IIFE can throw an error:

```js
function name({
  id = null, 
  name = 'user',
  password = (() => { throw new Error('password not defined'); })()
}) { 
  console.log(id, name, password);
}
  
name({ id: 1, name: 'the name', password: 'the password' }); // works

name({}); // throws an error
```