# Is the {foo = foo} validation trick in destructuring a safe pattern to adopt?

Tags: javascript, validation, destructuring

I've read this trick in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41536208/12696893),
that it's possible to validate for the presence of `foo` property like this:

```
const {foo = foo} = bar
```

It throws *Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'foo' before initialization* when `foo` is `undefined`.

Is this a well-defined behaviour in JS? Would this work reliably for all recent JavaScript versions and environments (browser, node) and likely future ones?

I am trying to see if it could make sense to start using this as a convenient shorthand validation if I don't care about having a more specific error message.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a well-defined behaviour in JS?

Yes. It relies on the [temporal dead zone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33198849/1048572) of `const` and `let` variables. It might not work if these are transpiled to `var` though.

> I am trying to see if it could make sense to start using this as a convenient shorthand validation

No, please don't. This is really obscure and confusing code, and every linter will complain about use-before-define. Even if you don't care about a specific error message, at least use

```
const {foo = error()} = bar;
```

with a throwing `error` function to make the intention clear.

Comment: Thanks! Agree that it's confusing code, and IDE / lint will not like it either... so better to go with the error function alternative. I wanted to avoid importing that everywhere and trying to find a JS built-in feature to do this.